# sprt-printer and Android 11

Tags: android, android-11, thermal-printer, bluetooth-printing

My App prints (sprt-printer) without errors or issues in Android 8 thru 10, but in Android 11 (Samsung Tab Active3) it can't print the whole ticket
It always stop half way.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code is really big  ...............can you give me your email and send it to you